# How to check whether a directory is a sub directory of another directory

Tags: python, security, validation, filesystems

I like to write a template system in Python, which allows to include files.

e.g.

```
    This is a template
    You can safely include files with safe_include`othertemplate.rst`
```

As you know, including files might be dangerous. For example, if I use the template system in a web application which allows users to create their own templates, they might do something like

```
I want your passwords: safe_include`/etc/password`
```

So therefore, I have to restrict the inclusion of files to files which are for example in a certain subdirectory (e.g. `/home/user/templates`)

The question is now: How can I check, whether `/home/user/templates/includes/inc1.rst` is in a subdirectory of `/home/user/templates`?

Would the following code work and be secure?

```
import os.path

def in_directory(file, directory, allow_symlink = False):
    #make both absolute    
    directory = os.path.abspath(directory)
    file = os.path.abspath(file)

    #check whether file is a symbolic link, if yes, return false if they are not allowed
    if not allow_symlink and os.path.islink(file):
        return False

    #return true, if the common prefix of both is equal to directory
    #e.g. /a/b/c/d.rst and directory is /a/b, the common prefix is /a/b
    return os.path.commonprefix([file, directory]) == directory
```

As long, as `allow_symlink` is False, it should be secure, I think. Allowing symlinks of course would make it insecure if the user is able to create such links.

**UPDATE - Solution**
The code above does not work, if intermediate directories are symbolic links.
To prevent this, you have to use `realpath` instead of `abspath`.

**UPDATE:** adding a trailing / to directory to solve the problem with commonprefix() Reorx pointed out.

This also makes `allow_symlink` unnecessary as symlinks are expanded to their real destination

```
import os.path

def in_directory(file, directory):
    #make both absolute    
    directory = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(directory), '')
    file = os.path.realpath(file)

    #return true, if the common prefix of both is equal to directory
    #e.g. /a/b/c/d.rst and directory is /a/b, the common prefix is /a/b
    return os.path.commonprefix([file, directory]) == directory
```

Comment: The last function doesn't work also, see this input and output: `>>> in_directory('/usr/var2/log', '/usr/var')
True
'`, `commonprefix` should not be trusted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854421/how-to-determine-if-a-path-is-a-subdirectory-of-another/18115718#18115718

Comment: Best answer is in the question ...

Comment: It defies common sense why `os.path.commonprefix(..)` was written to operate character-by-character, but that's indeed what the [documentation for it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) says.

Comment: **tl;dr:** For those still stuck on Python 3.4, see [jme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231929/jme)'s [inefficient `pathlib`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236245/2809027); for everyone else, see [Tom Bull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2010738/tom-bull)'s [efficient `commonpath`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37095733/2809027). Ignore both the answer embedded in this question *and* the accepted answer – all of which are blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

os.path.realpath(path): Return the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path (if they are supported by the operating system).

Use it on directory and subdirectory name, then check latter starts with former.

Comment: security vulnerability: see comment by Reorx on OP for example.

Comment: actually, you need to append the os.sep (if not already included) when calling startswith, as noted by jgoeders,

Comment: 'a/b/cde' starts with 'a/b/c' but is not a subdirectory.

Answer (score 114):

Python 3's `pathlib` module makes this straightforward with its [Path.parents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) attribute. For example:

```
from pathlib import Path

root = Path('/path/to/root')
child = root / 'some' / 'child' / 'dir'
other = Path('/some/other/path')
```

Then:

```
>>> root in child.parents
True
>>> other in child.parents
False
```

Comment: If you consider a path to be a child / parent of itself (for example if you want to test if a path is either `/a/b/c` or a subdirectory of `/a/b/c`) then you can use `root in [child] + [p for p in child.parents]`

Comment: Most Pythonic way for Python 3, `pathlib` really makes things easier to read.  It would be worth mentioning if you're playing a lot with relative paths that you might want to call `.resolve()` before checking if `A in B.parents`.

Comment: It's easier and more robust to use try/except on Path.relative_to() as documented my answer

Comment: `root in [child] + [p for p in child.parents]` can be simplified to `root in (child, *child.parents)`

Comment: It's important to mention that it's a hard requirement to call `resolve()` on the `child` first. Otherwise if the child is within ANY part of the root it'll return `True`.

Comment: Python 3.9 added `is_relative_to` to `pathlib' which performs this directly.

Comment: @omni I think that's bad advice. Calling `resolve()` blindly expands absolute symbolic links.  Let's say my current working directory is in `/a` and a contains a symbolic link `/a/b` pointing to `/x/y`.  Now logically `b` is in `a` **But** `Path('b').resolve() in Path('/a')` would return False.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I guess it depends on what you want to do. For most cases it's considered dangerous to follow symbolic links. Only working with the actual folder structure is safer. E.g. many webserver exploits inherit from this.

Comment: @omni generally you follow symbolic links unless you have a specific security requirement not to, otherwise they would be completely useless.  But it's certainly not true that calling `resolve()` is a hard requirement.  In most cases people should use `absolute()` unless they know a specific reason to resolve symbolic links first.  In that case the call to `resolve()` makes a call to `absolute()` redundant.

Answer (score 48):

#### Problems with many of the suggested methods

If you're going to test for directory parentage with string comparison or `os.path.commonprefix` methods, these are prone to errors with similarly-named paths or relative paths. For example:

- `/path/to/files/myfile` would be shown as a child path of `/path/to/file` using many of the methods.
- `/path/to/files/../../myfiles` would not be shown as a parent of `/path/myfiles/myfile` by many of the methods. In fact, it is.

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624617/2010738) by Rob Dennis provides a good way to compare path parentage without encountering these problems. Python 3.4 added the `pathlib` module which can perform these kind of path operations in a more sophisticated way, optionally without referencing the underlying OS. jme has described in [another previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236245/2010738) how to use `pathlib` for the purpose of accurately determining if one path is a child of another. If you prefer not to use `pathlib` (not sure why, it's pretty great) then Python 3.5 introduced a new OS-based method in `os.path` that allows you to do perform path parent-child checks in a similarly accurate and error-free manner with a lot less code.

#### New for Python 3.5

Python 3.5 introduced the function `os.path.commonpath`. This is a method that is specific to the OS that the code is running on. You can use `commonpath` in the following way to accurately determine path parentage:

```
def path_is_parent(parent_path, child_path):
    # Smooth out relative path names, note: if you are concerned about symbolic links, you should use os.path.realpath too
    parent_path = os.path.abspath(parent_path)
    child_path = os.path.abspath(child_path)

    # Compare the common path of the parent and child path with the common path of just the parent path. Using the commonpath method on just the parent path will regularise the path name in the same way as the comparison that deals with both paths, removing any trailing path separator
    return os.path.commonpath([parent_path]) == os.path.commonpath([parent_path, child_path])
```

#### Accurate one-liner

You can combine the whole lot into a one-line if statement in Python 3.5. It's ugly, it includes unnecessary duplicate calls to `os.path.abspath` and it definitely won't fit in the PEP 8 79-character line-length guidelines, but if you like that kind of thing, here goes:

```
if os.path.commonpath([os.path.abspath(parent_path_to_test)]) == os.path.commonpath([os.path.abspath(parent_path_to_test), os.path.abspath(child_path_to_test)]):
    # Yes, the child path is under the parent path
```

#### New for Python 3.9

`pathlib` has a new method on `PurePath` called `is_relative_to` which performs this function directly. You can read [the python documentation on how `is_relative_to` works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_relative_to) if you need to see how to use it. Or you can see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66626684/2010738) for a more full description of how to use it.

Comment: WTF would it be necessarry to take a commonpath of 1 path ?

imo:
    abs_parent_path==commonpath([abs_parent_path, abs_child_path])
should suffice ...

Comment: @MiloslavRaus is correct. Since the `os.path.abspath` and `os.path.realpath` functions implicitly chomp trailing directory separators, there's no need to call `os.path.commonpath` on a single dirname (e.g., `'/usr' == os.path.abspath('/usr/') == os.path.realpath('/usr/')`). In all other respects, this answer remains the most efficient and robust solution for Python 3.5+.

Comment: NOTE: The `is_relative_to()` method does NOT accurately deal with `../`. E.g.: `Path('/test1/../test2/myfile.txt').is_relative_to('/test2') == False`. If you have those in your path you need to use the **Accurate one-liner** instead of the New for Python 3.9 suggestion.

Comment: Regarding the solution described in this answer and ropeladder's comment, it should be mentioned that the functions `os.path.abspath` and `pathlib.Path.absolute()` and thus also `is_relative_to` **all assume that a relative path is meant as relative to the current working directory**. Depending on the use case, this assumption can be wrong, eg. if you read the relative path from some config file which assumes a different working directory. In such cases one can use (assuming parent and child are Path objects) `parent.resolve() in (parent / child).resolve().parents or child == parent`

Answer (score 14):

```
def is_subdir(path, directory):
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    directory = os.path.realpath(directory)
    relative = os.path.relpath(path, directory)
    return not relative.startswith(os.pardir + os.sep)
```

Comment: `os.path.relpath` does not include `os.sep` in my tests, e.g. `os.path.relpath("/a", "/a/b")`.

Comment: @TorstenBronger Good point. Therefore, the answer is wrong as it stands, unless the last line is changed to `return not (relative == os.pardir or relative.startswith(os.pardir + os.sep))`. By the way, if we insist on _proper_ subdirectory, then also check using `(relative == os.curdir)`.

Comment: If you're not on Python 2 don't use this but rather use pathlib as shown in other examples. If you're on Python 2: move.

Answer (score 11):

#### New for Python 3.9

`pathlib` has a new method on `PurePath` called `is_relative_to` which performs this function directly. You can read [the python documentation on how `is_relative_to` works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_relative_to), or use this example:

```
from pathlib import Path

child_path = Path("/path/to/file")
if child_path.is_relative_to("/path"):
    print("/path/to/file is a child of /path") # This prints
if child_path.is_relative_to("/anotherpath"):
    print("/path/to/file is a child of /anotherpath") # This does not print
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, in case of `child_path = Path("/path/to/../../file")` the condition give me wrong result. To fix this, should be `if child_path.resolve().is_relative_to("/path"):`

Answer (score 7):

so, I needed this, and due to the criticisms about commonprefx, I went a different way:

```
def os_path_split_asunder(path, debug=False):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/4580931/171094
    """
    parts = []
    while True:
        newpath, tail = os.path.split(path)
        if debug: print repr(path), (newpath, tail)
        if newpath == path:
            assert not tail
            if path: parts.append(path)
            break
        parts.append(tail)
        path = newpath
    parts.reverse()
    return parts


def is_subdirectory(potential_subdirectory, expected_parent_directory):
    """
    Is the first argument a sub-directory of the second argument?

    :param potential_subdirectory:
    :param expected_parent_directory:
    :return: True if the potential_subdirectory is a child of the expected parent directory

    >>> is_subdirectory('/var/test2', '/var/test')
    False
    >>> is_subdirectory('/var/test', '/var/test2')
    False
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test2', 'var/test')
    False
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test', 'var/test2')
    False
    >>> is_subdirectory('/var/test/sub', '/var/test')
    True
    >>> is_subdirectory('/var/test', '/var/test/sub')
    False
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test/sub', 'var/test')
    True
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test', 'var/test')
    True
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test', 'var/test/fake_sub/..')
    True
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test/sub/sub2/sub3/../..', 'var/test')
    True
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test/sub', 'var/test/fake_sub/..')
    True
    >>> is_subdirectory('var/test', 'var/test/sub')
    False
    """

    def _get_normalized_parts(path):
        return os_path_split_asunder(os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.normpath(path))))

    # make absolute and handle symbolic links, split into components
    sub_parts = _get_normalized_parts(potential_subdirectory)
    parent_parts = _get_normalized_parts(expected_parent_directory)

    if len(parent_parts) > len(sub_parts):
        # a parent directory never has more path segments than its child
        return False

    # we expect the zip to end with the short path, which we know to be the parent
    return all(part1==part2 for part1, part2 in zip(sub_parts, parent_parts))
```

Comment: All the string comparison / `os.path.commonprefix` methods are prone to errors with similarly-named paths or relative paths. This is a much better way of determining if a path is a child of another path and is not subject to the same bugs. If you're using Python 3.5+, there is a new method `os.path.commonpath` which lends itself to a simpler, more elegant method which is similarly accurate and will not lead to errors when paths are named similarly or specified as relative paths. I've provided a basic implementation in a separate answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
def is_in_directory(filepath, directory):
    return os.path.realpath(filepath).startswith(
        os.path.realpath(directory) + os.sep)
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the "path in other_path.parents" approached mentioned in another answer because I'm a big fan of pathlib, BUT I feel that approach is a bit heavy (it creates one Path instance for each parent to root of path). Also the case where path == other_path will fail with that approach, whereas os.commonpath would succeed on that case.

The following is a different approach, with its own set of pros and cons compared to other methods identified in the various answers:

```
try:
   other_path.relative_to(path)
except ValueError:
   ...no common path...
else:
   ...common path...
```

which is a little more verbose but can easily be added as a function in your application's common utilities module or even add the method to Path at startup time.

Comment: Oliver's answer appears to work, but `.resolve()` still needs to be called on both paths before running `.relative_to()`, if dealing with potentially relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I used below function for similar problem:

```
def is_subdir(p1, p2):
    """returns true if p1 is p2 or its subdirectory"""
    p1, p2 = os.path.realpath(p1), os.path.realpath(p2)
    return p1 == p2 or p1.startswith(p2+os.sep)
```

After running into problems with symbolic link I've modified the function. Now it checks if both paths are directories.

```
def is_subdir(p1, p2):
    """check if p1 is p2 or its subdirectory
    :param str p1: subdirectory candidate
    :param str p2: parent directory
    :returns True if p1,p2 are directories and p1 is p2 or its subdirectory"""
    if os.path.isdir(p1) and os.path.isdir(p2):
        p1, p2 = os.path.realpath(p1), os.path.realpath(p2)
        return p1 == p2 or p1.startswith(p2+os.sep)
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

with your inspirations, this method has been added to my utils:

```
def is_in_basefolder(path_to_check: PosixPath, basefolder: PosixPath):
        """
        check if a given path is in base folder
        
        parameters:
            path_to_check: a path to match with base folder
            basefolder: the base folder
        """
        path = path_to_check.resolve()
        base = basefolder.resolve()
        
        if path == base:
            return True
        
        if base.stem in path.parts:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: It would be useful to know how you would use this code. Perhaps give us a directory structure and a few scenarios where we can see the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
from typing import Union

def equals_or_contained(path: Union[str, os.PathLike], directory: Union[str, os.PathLike]) -> bool:
    """checks whether the path is inside the directory or is equal to it"""
    p = Path(path).absolute()
    d = Path(directory).absolute()
    if p == d:
        return True
    try:
        p.relative_to(d)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to the party here, but would `os.path.relpath` not solve the problem? The following should work, operating under the assumption that `os.path.relpath` computes the minimum relative path (so eg. `..` is not then followed by going back into the same directory).

```py
import os

def is_child_path(parentPath, childPath):
    try:
        # If the computed relative path starts with .. then it must
        # go above the parent, so cannot be a child.
        return not os.path.relpath(childPath, parentPath).startswith("..")
    except ValueError:
        # Raised on Windows if the drives are different.
        return False
```

Examples of this function being called:

```
>>> is_child_path("/a", "/a")               
True
>>> is_child_path("/a", "/a/b")
True
>>> is_child_path("/a", "/b") 
False
>>> is_child_path("/a", "/b/../a") 
True
>>> is_child_path("/a", "/a/../b") 
False
>>> is_child_path("a", "a/b")      
True
>>> is_child_path("a", "a/b/..") 
True
>>> is_child_path("a", "a/b/../..") 
False
```

This function depends only on `os`, and I believe relies on a path string-only computation, meaning the path does not have to exist on the filesystem. This does mean that it does not know (or care) about symlinks or the existence of files or directories, but you can easily use `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir` to check for existence, and `os.path.realpath` to resolve symlinks, before calling `is_child_path` itself.

Answer (score -1):

I would test the result from commonprefix against the filename to get a better answer, something like this:

```
def is_in_folder(filename, folder='/tmp/'):
    # normalize both parameters
    fn = os.path.normpath(filename)
    fd = os.path.normpath(folder)

    # get common prefix
    commonprefix = os.path.commonprefix([fn, fd])
    if commonprefix == fd:
        # in case they have common prefix, check more:
        sufix_part = fn.replace(fd, '')
        sufix_part = sufix_part.lstrip('/')
        new_file_name = os.path.join(fd, sufix_part)
        if new_file_name == fn:
            return True
        pass
    # for all other, it's False
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on another answer here, with correction, and with a user-friendlier name:

```
def isA_subdirOfB_orAisB(A, B):
    """It is assumed that A is a directory."""
    relative = os.path.relpath(os.path.realpath(A), 
                               os.path.realpath(B))
    return not (relative == os.pardir
            or  relative.startswith(os.pardir + os.sep))
```