# Extract a part of the filepath (a directory) in Python

Tags: python, directory, filepath

I need to extract the name of the parent directory of a certain path. This is what it looks like:

```
C:\stuff\directory_i_need\subdir\file.jpg
```

I would like to extract `directory_i_need`.

Comment: You might want to check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4580931/311220

Comment: The above link helped me understand how to fix what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31273488/1048186

Answer (score 327, accepted):

```
import os
## first file in current dir (with full path)
file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.listdir(os.getcwd())[0])
file
os.path.dirname(file) ## directory of file
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(file)) ## directory of directory of file
...
```

And you can continue doing this as many times as necessary...

**Edit:** from [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html), you can use either os.path.split or os.path.basename:

```
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(file)) ## dir of dir of file
## once you're at the directory level you want, with the desired directory as the final path node:
dirname1 = os.path.basename(dir) 
dirname2 = os.path.split(dir)[1] ## if you look at the documentation, this is exactly what os.path.basename does.
```

Comment: It does extract parts of the path - but I don't know how to extract the actual directory name from the path.

Comment: +1: A scenario where `os.path.dirname(path)` is handy compared to `pathlib.Path(path).parent`: You are given a string `path`. You want to create *the directory* of `path` if it does not exist, whether `path` itself is a directory or not. For example, `path` could be `/home/me/directory_to_create/file_to_create.txt` or `/home/me/directory_to_create/`. In the second case, `pathlib.Path(path).parent` returns `/home/me/` which is not desired.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend copying the second snippet verbatim, `dir()` is a reserved keyword in Python now: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 105):

For Python 3.4+, try the [`pathlib` module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> p = Path('C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe')

>>> str(p.parent)
'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer'

>>> p.name
'iexplore.exe'

>>> p.suffix
'.exe'

>>> p.parts
('C:\\', 'Program Files', 'Internet Explorer', 'iexplore.exe')

>>> p.relative_to('C:\\Program Files')
WindowsPath('Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe')

>>> p.exists()
True
```

Comment: nice demonstration of the API

Comment: This has also been backported to older versions of Python: [pathlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)

Comment: You example is wrong if your path contains for example \a. you should add r in front of the path' string.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar to the OP. This is the right answer. The accepted answer uses os.path.split which missed some path elements in my testing. pathlib Path works perfect for me

Answer (score 29):

All you need is `parent` part if you use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(r'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe')
print(p.parent)
```

Will output:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
```

Case you need all parts (already covered in other answers) use `parts`:

```
p = Path(r'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe')
print(p.parts)
```

Then you will get a list:

```
('C:\\', 'Program Files', 'Internet Explorer', 'iexplore.exe')
```

Saves tone of time.

Answer (score 5):

First, see if you have `splitunc()` as an available function within `os.path`. The first item returned should be what you want... but I am on Linux and I do not have this function when I import `os` and try to use it.

Otherwise, one semi-ugly way that gets the job done is to use:

```
>>> pathname = "\\C:\\mystuff\\project\\file.py"
>>> pathname
'\\C:\\mystuff\\project\\file.py'
>>> print pathname
\C:\mystuff\project\file.py
>>> "\\".join(pathname.split('\\')[:-2])
'\\C:\\mystuff'
>>> "\\".join(pathname.split('\\')[:-1])
'\\C:\\mystuff\\project'
```

which shows retrieving the directory just above the file, and the directory just above that.

Comment: I edited my entry to show use of rsplit which does what you suggest - but still gives me the path not just the directory name.

Comment: I ended up splitting the path and taking the piece I wanted, it didn't work before but after reading all these answers, I found out what I did wrong.

Comment: I like the way this semi-ugly way works. I change the "\\" by a simple os.sep and it works perfectly to retrieve just a fraction of a path.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

directory = os.path.abspath('\\') # root directory
print(directory) # e.g. 'C:\'

directory = os.path.abspath('.') # current directory
print(directory) # e.g. 'C:\Users\User\Desktop'

parent_directory, directory_name = os.path.split(directory)
print(directory_name) # e.g. 'Desktop'
parent_parent_directory, parent_directory_name = os.path.split(parent_directory)
print(parent_directory_name) # e.g. 'User'
```

This should also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the entire path as a parameter to os.path.split. See [The docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split). It doesn't work like string split.

Comment: This won't work on UNC type pathnames on Windows, as the Python docs for os.path stuff state.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to extract the piece of the directory:

```
for path in file_list:
  directories = path.rsplit('\\')
  directories.reverse()
  line_replace_add_directory = line_replace+directories[2]
```

Thank you for your help.