# Truncate path in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, path

Is there a way to truncate a long path in Python so it only displays the last couple or so directories? I thought I could use os.path.join to do this, but it just doesn't work like that. 
I've written the function below, but was curious to know if there is a more Pythonic way of doing the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

def shorten_folder_path(afolder, num=2):

  s = "...\\"
  p = os.path.normpath(afolder)
  pathList = p.split(os.sep)
  num = len(pathList)-num
  folders = pathList[num:]

  # os.path.join(folders) # fails obviously

  if num*-1 >= len(pathList)-1:
    folders = pathList[0:]
    s = ""

  # join them together
  for item in folders:
    s += item + "\\"

  # remove last slash
  return s.rstrip("\\")

print shorten_folder_path(r"C:\temp\afolder\something\project files\more files", 2)
print shorten_folder_path(r"C:\big project folder\important stuff\x\y\z\files of stuff", 1)
print shorten_folder_path(r"C:\folder_A\folder\B_folder_C", 1)
print shorten_folder_path(r"C:\folder_A\folder\B_folder_C", 2)
print shorten_folder_path(r"C:\folder_A\folder\B_folder_C", 3)


...\project files\more files
...\files of stuff
...\B_folder_C
...\folder\B_folder_C
...\folder_A\folder\B_folder_C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right when you tried to use `os.path`. You can simply use `os.path.split` or `os.path.basename` like this:

```
fileInLongPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.listdir(os.getcwd())[0]) # this will get the first file in the last directory of your path
os.path.dirname(fileInLongPath) # this will get directory of file
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(fileInLongPath)) # this will get the directory of the directory of the file
```

And just keep doing that as many times as necessary.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149358/6745924)

Answer (score 8):

The built-in [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module has some nifty methods to do this:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> 
>>> def shorten_path(file_path, length):
...     """Split the path into separate parts, select the last 
...     'length' elements and join them again"""
...     return Path(*Path(file_path).parts[-length:])
... 
>>> shorten_path('/path/to/some/very/deep/structure', 2)
PosixPath('deep/structure')
>>> shorten_path('/path/to/some/very/deep/structure', 4)
PosixPath('some/very/deep/structure')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and it seems like you are asking about truncating a path based on an integer, however, it's also pretty easy to truncate based on a folder name.

Here is an example of truncating to the current working directory:

```
import os
from os import path as ospath
from os.path import join

def ShortenPath(path):
    split_path = ospath.split("/")
    cwd = os.getcwd().split("/")[-1]

    n = [x for x in range(len(split_path)) if split_path[x] == cwd]
    n = n[0] if n != [] else -1

    return join(".", *[d for d in split_path if split_path.index(d) > n]) if n >= 0 else path
```

Input `"/home/user_name/some_folder/inner_folder"`

Current Working Directory `"some_folder"`

Return `"./inner_folder"`

Maybe there is a built-in way of doing this but idk.