# Get file path without file name

Tags: python

Given a file path

```
/path/to/some/file.jpg
```

How would I get

```
/path/to/some
```

I'm currently doing

```
fullpath = '/path/to/some/file.jpg'
filepath = '/'.join(fullpath.split('/')[:-1])
```

But I think it is open to errors

Comment: Don't assume that the path separator is always `/` if you are planning to run this on different operating systems.

Comment: Its for an internal project where we could set a standard, but you are right, someone might input a filepath from a different OS where its \ instead of /

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract a part of the filepath (a directory) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149263/extract-a-part-of-the-filepath-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: Best way to do this is using [the OS-independent `pathlib` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67749020/5717580).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split):

```
dirname, fname = os.path.split(fullpath)
```

Per the docs:

> Split the pathname *path* into a pair, `(head, tail)` where *tail* is the
>   last pathname component and *head* is everything leading up to that. The
>   *tail* part will never contain a slash; if *path* ends in a slash, *tail*
>   will be empty. If there is no slash in *path*, *head* will be empty.

`os.path` is always the module suitable for the platform that the code is running on.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
fullpath = '/path/to/some/file.jpg'

import os
os.path.dirname(fullpath)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you can get the path without the file name using the `.parent` attribute:

```py
from pathlib import Path

fullpath = Path("/path/to/some/file.jpg")
filepath = str(fullpath.parent)  # /path/to/some/
```

This handles both UNIX and Windows paths correctly.

Answer (score 0):

With String [rfind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) method.

```py
fullpath = '/path/to/some/file.jpg'
index = fullpath.rfind('/')
fullpath[0:index]
```

Comment: What about this: `'/path/to/some//file.jpg'` or `'C:\path\to\some\file.jpg'`?

Comment: Based on the users given and then criteria, this should be good. But I agree this would not work in case of different OS.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly with my first example either. We should not suggest fail-prone methods when there is a documented, platform agnostic built-in method of doing something, such as the `os.path.split` method suggested by @LevLevitsky. The OP has suggested a similar method themselves but they are looking for a **better** method because they _think it is open to errors_.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.