# Python os.walk/fnmatch.filter does not find file when in file's current directory

Tags: python, io, os.walk

I'm trying to recursively walk through a directory and find files that match a certain pattern. The relevant snippet of my code is:

```
import sys, os, xlrd, fnmatch

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/myfilepath/'):

    for dir in dirnames:
        os.chdir(os.path.join(root, dir))

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'filepattern*'):
            print os.path.abspath(filename)
            print os.getcwd()
            print filename

            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
```

My print lines demonstrate that `os.getcwd()` is equal to the directory of filename, so to me it seems like the file should be found, but `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` is thrown for `wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)` when the first pattern is matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dirnames` returned from `os.walk` don't represent the directories in which `filenames` exist. Rather, `root` represents the directory in which `filenames` exist. For your application you can effectively ignore the `directories` return.

Try something like this:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for root, _, filenames in os.walk('/tmp'):
    print root, filenames
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.py'):
        filename = os.path.join(root, filename)

        # `filename` now unambiguously refers to a file that
        # exists. Open it, delete it, xlrd.open it, whatever.
        # For example:
        if os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
            print "%s can be accessed"  % filename
        else:
            print "%s cannot be accessed"  % filename
```

*Aside*: It is probably not safe to call `os.chdir()` inside an `os.walk()` iteration. This is especially true if the parameter to `os.walk()` is relative.

Answer (score 1):

**Like linux find in Python?** 
A more powerfull techneque to find files exists, use *glob* which is like Linux find and it uses the very powerful *pathlib* to handle the different formats of paths.

Works with Python 3.5 or higher, I'm using version 3.7 and it works on old mac, friendly Linux and even on spy Windows 10.

Clear example (no partial scraps of code permitted).

```
import glob
import subprocess
from pathlib import PurePath

    # Return a list of matching files
    def find_files(start_dir, pattern, recurse=True):
        patt = start_dir.strip() + '/**/' + pattern
        files = []
        for f in glob.iglob(patt, recursive=recurse):
            files.append(PurePath(f))
        return files
```

When *recurse* is *True* it finds the files matching the pattern in the current and child directories.
When recurse is *False*, just the local current directory is searched.

glob.iglob() is an itererater version of glob.glob() and both output the same, except the iterator version does not accumulate the results untill needed.

**USAGE EXAMPLE from inside a git project searching for source files using Python**

```
cmd = ['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel']

result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
gitroot = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')

print(gitroot)

ret = find_files(gitroot, "os.c")
print(ret)
```

That found the git root of a git project, then from there searched for **os.c** or any pattern you like.

Yes it executed the git command:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

That is powerful, so that means you can search and act on files.
Hope that helps - see the output and notice the path formats mixed up.
That is bacause Windows is still confused and Linux (the Posix standard) is not.

**OUTPUT**

```
C:\Users\me\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/me/7pych/git_find_file.py *.c
C:/Users/me/git_projects/demo

[PureWindowsPath('C:/Users/me/git_projects/demo/device/src/os/os.c')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

To obtain **just the path name** or **just the file** name use *split()*.  See this example:
[cross-platform splitting of path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579908/cross-platform-splitting-of-path-in-python/4579972#4579972)