# How do I pull last 3 levels from a file path in python?

Tags: python, path, os.path

I have a file path

> filePath = "dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file.txt"

How do I pull the last 3 levels from the path?
Output:

> newFilePath = "dir4/dir5/file.txt"

Comment: This might be what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579908/cross-platform-splitting-of-path-in-python/4580931#4580931

Answer (score 3):

You can use split and join to get the last n from some file path. For example,

```py
test = "some/dir/somewhere/here/"
new = "/".join(i for i in test.split("/")[-4:])
print(new) # 'dir/somewhere/here/'
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that there exists no "/" anywhere else in the path.