# how to read a file with flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am performing a recursive list of folders. I show the List on the Web with their respective links. I would like to click on a file name and be able to read the content on the web.
I show the code below:

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def mostrar_subcarpeta():
    carpeta = "/home/user/"
    lista_html = "<div>"
    lista_html = "<div>"
    for raiz, dirs, archivos in os.walk(carpeta):    
        splitRaiz = raiz.split('/') or raiz.split('\\') 
        
        lista_html += f"<div>{splitRaiz[-1]}</div>"
        for archivo in archivos:
            lista_html += "</div>"
            lista_html += "<ul>"            
            lista_html += f"<li><a href={raiz}/{ archivo }>{ archivo }</a></li>"           
            lista_html += "</ul>"
            lista_html += "</div>"
            
    return lista_html

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: You should learn HTML first. Each <div> should have a </div> pair. In the for cycle there are two many /div-s and no div-s, At the and there is no /div.
    lista_html = "<div>"
    lista_html = "<div>" is not different than just one assignment. You don't add to the string there, just assignt the same value twice.
Splitting path is better with standerd library functions https://stackoverflow.com/a/31273488/813946

Comment: Thank you Arpad Horvath -- Слава Україні for the recommendation to use```splitRaiz = os.path.split(raiz)```