# How to determine if a path is a subdirectory of another?

Tags: python, file

I am given a list of paths that I need to check files within. Of course, if I am given a root, and a subdirectory, there is no need to process the sub-directory. For example

```plaintext
c:\test  // process this
c:\test\pics // do not process this
c:\test2 // process this
```

How can I tell (cross platform) that a path is not a subdirectory of the other. Preferably I would want this to be cross platform, and am not worried about symlinks as long as they are not cyclical (worse case is that I end up processing the data twice).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would maintain a set of directories you have already processed, and then for each new path check to see if any of its parent directories already exist in that set before processing:

```
import os.path

visited = set()
for path in path_list:
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    while head and tail:
        if head in visited:
            break
        head, tail = os.path.split(head)
    else:
        process(path)
        visited.add(path)
```

Note that `path_list` should be sorted so that subdirectories are always after their parent directories if they exist.

Comment: This will be faster than my suggestion because it does set membership tests rather than scanning a list. I like it.

Comment: @F.J seems to be an infitie loop, head reduces to c:\ at its very base and never gets set to None.

Comment: @esac - Sorry about that, I had thought that in the base case it would put everything into tail, not head.  See my edit which should fix the problem.

Comment: @F.J still an infinite loop, if head is in the visited list, the head pointer is never updated, so it will be stuck in continue forever

Comment: @esac - Right you are, sorry about the sloppy code!  It should actually be fixed now.

Comment: @F.J no worries, i already got it working with a boolean if, but you just taught me something new with the else, pretty cool!

Comment: using `visited` seems rather risky, especially for long running processes, where it may grow beyond the systems memory.

Answer (score 8):

```
def is_subdir(path, directory):
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    directory = os.path.realpath(directory)

    relative = os.path.relpath(path, directory)

    if relative.startswith(os.pardir):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Using `relpath` can fail on ms-windows, when attempting to find `C:\foo` relative to `D:\bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Track the directories you've already processed (in a normalized form) and don't process them again if you've already seen them. Something like this should work:

```
from os.path import realpath, normcase, sep

dirs = [r"C:\test", r"C:\test\pics", r"C:\test2"]

processed = []

for dir in dirs:
    dir = normcase(realpath(dir)) + sep
    if not any(dir.startswith(p) for p in processed):
        processed.append(dir)
        process(dir)            # your code here
```

Comment: `commonprefix([r'C:\test2', r'C:\test']) --> 'C:\\test'`

Comment: Yeah, sigh. That doesn't really do what it should, IMHO. Changed it to just do a simple `startswith()` -- that'll be fine since it's normalized.

Comment: Yeah, I really think the behavior of commonprefix is kind of weird, it seems like it should only check at directory breaks, since it comes from the `os.path` module, oh well.

Comment: @F.J. Just as a point of interest: `commonprefix` accepts a list of _any kind of sequences_ (not just strings). So a list of lists containing path components will work as expected (although this is probably not by design).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and simplified [jgoeders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609215/jgoeders)'s version:

```
def is_subdir(suspect_child, suspect_parent):
    suspect_child = os.path.realpath(suspect_child)
    suspect_parent = os.path.realpath(suspect_parent)

    relative = os.path.relpath(suspect_child, start=suspect_parent)

    return not relative.startswith(os.pardir)
```

Comment: Why not just edit the post instead of adding another duplicate answer?

Comment: Sorry, I post on SO once in a blue Moon, and missed this feature.

Comment: `realpath` - eliminating symbolic links here is problematic. (in many cases not what you want), since following links can change the path layout completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `is_subdir` utility function I came up with.

- Python3.x compatible (works with `bytes` and `str`, matching `os.path` which also supports both).
- Normalizes paths for comparison.
  *(parent hierarchy and case to work on ms-windows).*
- Avoids using `os.path.relpath` which will raise an exception on ms-windows if the paths are on different drives. (`C:\foo` -> `D:\bar`)

Code:

```
def is_subdir(path, directory):
    """
    Returns true if *path* in a subdirectory of *directory*.
    """
    import os
    from os.path import normpath, normcase, sep
    path = normpath(normcase(path))
    directory = normpath(normcase(directory))
    if len(path) > len(directory):
        sep = sep.encode('ascii') if isinstance(directory, bytes) else sep
        if path.startswith(directory.rstrip(sep) + sep):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used based off Andrew Clarks answer, making sure the list is sorted so that children are under parents, and using `normpath` and `normcase` to fix paths that refer to the same location such as `c:\users` and `c:/users` in Windows.

```py
  def unique_path_roots(paths):
    visited = set()
    paths = list(set(paths))

    for path in sorted(paths,key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)):
        path = normcase(normpath(realpath(path)))

        head, tail = os.path.split(path)
        while head and tail:
            if head in visited:
                break
            head, tail = os.path.split(head)
        else:
            yield path
            visited.add(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could build something like this using `Path("x").is_relative_to`