# Python: How to check if path is a subpath

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

Lets say I have these paths:

```
/tmp/a
/tmp/abc
/tmp/abc/d/my_file.py
```

How could I check if `/tmp/abc/d/my_file.py` is a subpath of `/tmp/abc`? I tried:

```
file_path.startswith(dir_path)
```

But it returns `True` for `/tmp/a` directory, while `my_file.py` is not in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this:
`file_path.startswith(os.path.abspath(dir_path)+os.sep)`

also you can check on this:
[How to check whether a directory is a sub directory of another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812849/how-to-check-whether-a-directory-is-a-sub-directory-of-another-directory)

so for your example:

```
>>> '/tmp/abc/d/my_file.py'.startswith(os.path.abspath('/tmp/abc')+os.sep)
True
>>> '/tmp/abc/d/my_file.py'.startswith(os.path.abspath('/tmp/a')+os.sep)
False
```

Comment: probably want to check if `file_path.startswith(os.path.abspath(dir_path)+os.sep)` or `file_path == dir_path`

Comment: This solution might introduce some security issues because it doesn't take directory walking (adding multiple '..' to the path) into account. You should compare the results from os.path.realpath().

Comment: @AndreasKraft why `realpath` vs `normpath`?

Comment: normpath() also normalizes the path to the OS representation. This means, for example, using "\" as separators under Windows, which again makes it harder to use in comparisons.

Comment: This is wrong. It incorrectly returns `False` when `dir_path` is `/`.